# Consume windows authendicated web service using Ksoap2 from android app

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I am working in an android application and I am consuming a web service that has implemented Basic authentication in android using Ksoap2. But now my web service has been changed to windows authentication from basic. Is there any way to consume this web service using Ksoap2.6.5

My code which I used to consume basic authentication.

```
List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ org.kobjects.base64.Base64
.encode("Username:Password".getBytes())));
androidHttpTransport.call(soapaction, envelope, headerList);
```